# Clone table and display after button

Tags: javascript, html

Great day Community,i'm facing clone whole table problem, if it have solution of clone several row it will be helping a lots.

If using **document.getElementsByTagName("table")[2]**; it can clone the table and put it in body because i'm using **document.body.appendChild(myClone)** to do it.

**Here is some code:**

**Solution 1:**

```
function myFunction() {

      myTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[2];  // doesn't use any table id
      myClone = myTable.cloneNode(true);
      var y = document.body.appendChild(myClone);
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("0");  // using this to find auto genereate id for table
      test =  x.cloneNode(true);
    }
```

**Html Display:**

```
<table>
     <tr>
      <td>
         <table id="0">
           <tr>
               <td><span></span>Name:<input type="text" value="Tom"/>  </td>
               <td><span> </span>Age:<input type="text" value="25"/>  </td>
               <td><span> </span>Email:<input type="text" value="tom@gmail.com"/>  </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <table id="1">
           <tr>
               <td><span></span>Name:<input type="text" value="Alice"/>  </td>
               <td><span> </span>Age:<input type="text" value="22"/>  </td>
               <td><span> </span>Email:<input type="text" value="alice@gmail.com"/>  </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
         <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Expected result clone the table after the button, the table inside  will not have more than 5. 
Please help thank you.

Comment: Can you please upload your working code on Fiddle or Codepen?

Comment: I'm baffled by the structure of your table. Wouldn't it be better to have a table in which each row contains the three cells (name, age and email) rather than each row containing a new table with a row with three cells?

Comment: @VirgilioGM yes is kind of baffled but it need to grow this way because of the complicated data behind, i only put the easy identify row to find help from here

Comment: In this case, you must insert in each tr of the main table a td containing the tables that will be cloned. In a few minutes I will elaborate and put a complete answer

Comment: Check my answer and let me know what do you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Dominic Amal Joe F's answer was on the right track, it had some flaws, as well as the structure of the OP table. I think this code would work properly:

```js
function myFunction(){
  // get main table body
  var tableBody = document.getElementById('mytable').children[0];

  // get existing rows
  var rows = tableBody.children.length;

  // clone the last row (which contains the last table)
  var newRow = tableBody.children[rows-1].cloneNode(true);

  // get the new row table
  var newTable = newRow.children[0].children[0]

  // change the table id
  newTable.setAttribute('id', rows);

  // reset the inputs values
  var cells = newTable.children[0].children[0].children;
  for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].children[1].value = "";
  }

  // append the new row to the main table body
  tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="0">
        <tr>
          <td><span>Name:</span><input type="text" value="Tom"/></td>
          <td><span>Age:</span><input type="number" value="25"/></td>
          <td><span>Email:</span><input type="email" value="tom@gmail.com"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="1">
        <tr>
          <td><span>Name:</span><input type="text" value="Alice"/></td>
          <td><span>Age:</span><input type="number" value="22"/></td>
          <td><span>Email:</span><input type="email" value="alice@gmail.com"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Clone</button>
```

Comment: yes i forget to add in <td> in the table. thank you for showing solution, i will take a try if it works i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the following code will help you.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<button onclick="myFunction()">clone</button>
<tr>
    <table id="parent-table">
      <tr id="parent-row">
          <td><span></span>Name:<input type="text" value="Tom"/>  </td>
          <td><span> </span>Age:<input type="text" value="25"/>  </td>
          <td><span> </span>Email:<input type="text" value="tom@gmail.com"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction(){
  let parentTable = document.getElementById("parent-table");
  let parentRow = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')
  let clone = parentRow[1].cloneNode(true);
      parentTable.appendChild(clone)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, i will not have any id for <tr> because the <tr> inside the table will be dynamic depend on records of data receive and generate the table, maximum is 5 table in the <tr>

Comment: @Victor please check the another solution

Comment: `<table>
<input type="button" value="clone" onclick="myFunction()"/>
<tr>` is not valid html

Comment: @DominicAmalJoeF i have update the table <td> i will try your suggestion will let you know if it works thank you.

Comment: @DominicAmalJoeF that is still invalid html, you should not add things between table creation elements